# angularjs, make router work for same url but with different number of GET parameters

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

is there a posiibility to tell angularjs route config to ignore get parameters,
like we have a page with list of items with url: site.com/request/list, router works fine but when we add sorting/filtering we have to show the same page, but router fails with url like 
site.com/request/list/sort/quantity/order/desc or site.com/request/list/sort/quantity?

Thanks.

Comment: There are currently no wildcards in angular routes. If the number of route parameters is finite, you can simply define all different routes separately and let them use the same controller.

Comment: It is the way I use now but this is the way I want to get rid of. Strange, as the case is quite common.